# Country, state list for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi In a application i need to list all countries in the world , we i select a country  all the states corresponding to it should be listed, if i select as state all the cities in that state should listed.

I have created the tables with references in SQL Server 2005.

I need the complete data list of countries , states, cities Is there any solution or packages or files available so that we can import to SQL Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ISO country codes are [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm). You can download this in a number of formats (CSV etc) and using DTS or a similar product you ought to be able to import them into your database.

Once you get down to states or regions in countries it gets bit trickier. You may have to put these together yourself, or search for individual resources that provide them.

EDIT:

I found the US States [here](http://27.org/isocountrylist/), in MySQL format - which you can probably easily adapt.

Comment: It's easy enough to identify the states in the United States. But there are other geographic parts of the US which aren't "states". For example, Puerto Rico, Guam, US Virgin Islands. Even the District of Columbia. You'll want to be sure you have considered those as well.

Comment: i wanted the list of all countries, their states, cities everything, it would  be easier if something like SQL file is available

Comment: I'm not sure if such a thing exists. Keeping it up to date would be a lot of work. If you do some Googling you'll find it for certain countries, for e.g: http://dpi.careerbuilder.com/Site/Geography/ListStateprovcounty.aspx
You might also be able to find some third parties that provide this data - but you'll most likely pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

As leon01 said you can use GeoNames.

I did a small tool to generate an XML file based on the output of their webservices: https://github.com/yosoyadri/GeoNames-XML-Builder

All credit should really go to the C# library at http://geonamesdotorgdotnet.codeplex.com/ that I'm using to parse the response XML from the services.

You have an already made list of countries and provinces from this service at https://raw.github.com/yosoyadri/GeoNames-XML-Builder/master/continents-countries-statesprovinces.xml

Comment: In this Link, you can download the SQL Script for your requirement of Country-State(Province)-City at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sql-server-scripts-to-store-countries-states-and-cities-in-database1