# Countries and their province web service

Tags: asp.net

I need a webservice to get information of whole of the countries and their provinces location and area or population is anyone who knows this web service ?

Comment: Another (non-service) source of the data is [the UN's LOCODE](http://www.unece.org/cefact/codesfortrade/codes_index.htm)

Comment: the countries are updating always I need something official.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you need web service? I don't think so its exist.

what you need to do is, you can create table in your DB and add data, Its easy to find SQL insert queries to dump the data. please check these URLs

http://amrelgarhytech.blogspot.com/2008/08/list-of-countries-cities-languages.html

[Country, state list for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157757/country-state-list-for-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the great service from the chaps at http://www.geonames.org/

I did a small tool to generate an XML file based on the output of their webservices: https://github.com/yosoyadri/GeoNames-XML-Builder

All credit should really go to the C# library at http://geonamesdotorgdotnet.codeplex.com/ that I'm using to parse the response XML from the services.

You have an already made list of countries and provinces at https://raw.github.com/yosoyadri/GeoNames-XML-Builder/master/continents-countries-statesprovinces.xml

As Muhammad I think it is always good practice to keep your local copy of the data rather than querying the service everytime.